# Find and replace content within string (C#)

Tags: c#, string, parsing, string-parsing, replace

The below string is coming from a DIV tag. So I have enclosed the value below.

```
String cLocation = "'target="_blank'></a><img alt='testimage.jpg' src='/SPECIMAGE/testimage.jpg'"
```

I would like to replace in the above string by changing `"src="/"` with `"src='xyz/files'"`.

I have tried the typical `string.Replace("old","new")` but it didn't work.

I tried the below,

```
cNewLocation ="xyz/files";
cNewString = cLocation.Replce("src='/'", "src='" + cNewLocation + "'/")
```

It didn't work.

Please suggest.

Comment: That is not a valid string literal in C#. Please post actual code.

Comment: Your question title contains a key to answer itself, have you tried google or look into the auto-suggested posts on StackOverflow whilst posting an answer?

Comment: @sll - Googling would require effort, you know, clicking links and reading documentation. Much too difficult.

Comment: I could not complete the post and it saved and posted. Read above comments.

Comment: Well it did not work because you have no `"src='/'"` in your string. You have `src='/SPECIMAGE/testimage.jpg'`, and that's different.

Comment: thanks for voting it down but whoever did that should read it fully and then do it.

Comment: Votes down have been made when your only question was "*how to replace a String*". Now *@CAbbott*'s solution might be the one you want if I understand right your mistake.

Comment: @Otiel -> I enclosed / withink '/' after it gave errors.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please write *exactly* the input string you have, and *exactly* the output string you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, you could use Regex to replace the string like so:

```
var cNewString = Regex.Replace(cLocation, @"src='/.*/", "src='" + newLocation + "/");
```

**EDIT :** I modified the regular expression to replace `src='/.../` with `src='{newLocation}/`

Comment: I think your first solution is the one the OP needs actually.

Comment: @Otiel - yeah, I changed the regular expression to fit with the substitution I believe the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you might try looking at the Replace command in c#.

so `mystring = srcstring.Replace("old", "New");`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

possible replace the `/` in the string with `//`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
string cLocation = "'target='_blank'></a><img alt='testimage.jpg' src='/SPECIMAGE/testimage.jpg'";
cLocation = cLocation.Replace("src='/'", "src='xyz/files'");
```

Comment: There's a stray apostrophe in there, by the looks of it. Should probably be `cLocation = cLocation.Replace("src='/", "src='xyz/files/");`

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the problem:

```
int start = cLocation.IndexOf("src='") + 5;
int end = cLocation.LastIndexOf("'");
string xcLocation = cLocation.Remove(start, end - start);
string cLocation = xcLocation.Insert(start , "xyz/files");
```